# UTF8 support on cross platform C application

Tags: c, utf-8, internationalization, cross-platform

I am developing a cross platform C (C89 standard) application which has to deal with UTF8 text. All I need is basic string manipulation functions like `substr`, `first`, `last` etc.

**Question 1**

Is there a UTF8 library that has the above functions implemented? I have already looked into ICU and it is too big for my requirement. I just need to support UTF8.

I have found a UTF8 decoder [here](http://www.json.org/JSON_checker/utf8_decode.c). Following function prototypes are from that code.

```
void utf8_decode_init(char p[], int length);

int utf8_decode_next();
```

The initialization function takes a character array but `utf8_decode_next()` returns `int`. Why is that? How can I print the characters this function returns using standard functions like `printf`? The function is dealing with character data and how can that be assigned to a integer?

If the above decoder is not good for production code, do you have a better recommendation?

**Question 2**

I also got confused by reading articles that says, for unicode you need to use `wchar_t`. From my understanding this is not required as normal C strings can hold UTF8 values. I have verified this by looking at source code of SQLite and git. SQLite has the following typedef.

```
typedef unsigned char u8
```

Is my understanding correct? Also why is `unsigned char` required?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The `utf_decode_next()` function returns the next Unicode code point.  Since Unicode is a 21-bit character set, it cannot return anything smaller than an `int`, and it can be argued that technically, it should be a `long` since an `int` could be a 16-bit quantity.  Effectively, the function returns you a UTF-32 character.

   You would need to look at the C94 wide character extensions to C89 to print wide characters (`wprintf()`, `<wctype.h>`, `<wchar.h>`).  However, wide characters alone are not guaranteed to be UTF-8 or even Unicode.  You most probably cannot print the characters from `utf8_decode_next()` portably, but it depends on what your portability requirements are.  The wider the range of systems you must port to, the less chance there is of it all working simply.  To the extent you can write UTF-8 portably, you would send the UTF-8 string (not an array of the UTF-32 characters obtained from `utf8_decode_next()`) to one of the regular printing functions.  One of the strengths of UTF-8 is that it can be manipulated by code that is largely ignorant of it.
2. You need to understand that a 4-byte `wchar_t` can hold any Unicode codepoint in a single unit, but that UTF-8 can require between one and four 8-bit bytes (1-4 units of storage) to hold a single Unicode codepoint.  On some systems, I believe `wchar_t` can be a 16-bit (`short`) integer.  In this case, you are forced into using UTF-16, which encodes Unicode codepoints outside the Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP, code points U+0000 .. U+FFFF) using two storage units and surrogates.

   Using `unsigned char` makes life easier; plain `char` is often signed.  Having negative numbers makes life more difficult than it need me (and, believe me, it is difficult enough without adding complexity).

Comment: `int32_t` would be the preferred type for Unicode codepoints. As you say, `int` could in theory be to short, and `long` will certainly be a huge waste of space on any 64-bit machine.

Comment: @R..: Fair comment; and with only the less-significant 21 of the 32 bits in use, there's no need to worry about `uint32_t` vs `int32_t`.

Comment: I like using a signed type in order to easily be able to use negative values for errors, but during decoding, unsigned types are often more convenient. It really doesn't matter which you use as long as it's a 32-bit type, as you said.

Comment: It's a crying shame that few implementations provide `int_least22_t`. What are they thinking?

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan. I have implemented `substr` and `length` and not used the above decoder. It looks like the new implementation is more simple. It is posted here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501621/utf8-support-on-cross-platform-c-application/4534339#4534339

Answer (score 4):

You do not need any special library routines for character or substring search with UTF-8. `strstr` does everything you need. That's the whole point of UTF-8 and the design requirements it was invented to meet.

Comment: @R.. Thanks. So just to understand, `strstr` has a UTF8 decoder?

Comment: No, because it doesn't need one. That is **the whole point of UTF-8**.

Comment: thanks a lot. I am sorry but I am still bit confused. As per my understanding, since UTF8 is not subjected to byte ordering, comparing the bytes itself will give correct information and you don't need to decode it. That's why `strstr` is working with UTF8. Is that correct?

Comment: Suppose you're looking for the string `"Áx"`, represented as the bytes `C3 81 78` (hex) in the string `"ÄÁxy"` represented as the bytes `C3 84 C3 81 78 79`. How do you find it? Just look for the sequence of bytes; you find it at byte offset 2. This is how `strstr` works. Note that while both `Ä` and `Á` begin with `C3`, no character can ever be a substring of another character in UTF-8.

Comment: @R.. Just wanted to thank you again beause the `strstr` approach was simple. I have written a function that checks if a UTF8 string ends with the supplied character using `strstr` and it works well. But I now needs to remove certain characters from the UTF8 string and replace it with some other characters. In this case, I guess a decoder is required. Same stands for `substr` also. Do you have any experiences with `libunistring`? Have you tried running it on windows?

Comment: If you just work with characters, you can get in trouble *replacing* them since the new characters might be a different length in bytes. But the Unicode recommendation anyway is to avoid working with characters and always work with strings. If you go at it that way - replacing a substring with a new string - things will work just fine, but it will require either copying to a new buffer or performing some `memmove` in the existing buffer (and possibly resizing it).

Comment: that makes it more clear. I still haven't got a `substr` working as it has the same problem. I think it makes no sense to write a `substr(size_t pos, size_t len)` on UTF8 encoded string because of the variable length encoding. So I am not sure how about writing a function that uses `strstr` and removes the last character from the string when it matches the supplied argument. I will give it a shot and let you know the updates. Thanks again.

Comment: Characters in (valid) UTF-8 always start with a head byte `00-7F` or `C2-F4` and continue for all following bytes in the range `80-BF`. If you want the last character, you can start at the last byte and work backwards until you find a head-byte. On the other hand, if you know a particular character you're looking for, just compare that many bytes at the end of the string with the bytes of that character and see if they match. If so, write a null byte over top of the first one and you've removed it.

Comment: @R.. I have successfully implemented `substr` and a `length` function posted as an answer here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501621/utf8-support-on-cross-platform-c-application/4534339#4534339). I think I have got a decent idea about UTF8 strings. Can you please let me know if that implementation looks good? Your help was really valuable and I learned a lot of stuff. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

GLib has [quite a few](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/2.26/glib-Unicode-Manipulation.html) relevant functions, and can be used independent of GTK+.

Comment: can I compile this on windows?

Comment: Sure, but it's probably already compiled. You just need to grab the DLL, headers, and import libs. http://www.gtk.org/download-windows.html

Answer (score 1):

There are over 100,000 characters in Unicode. There are 256 possible values of `char` in most C implementations.

Hence, UTF-8 uses more than one `char` to encode each character, and the decoder needs a return type which is larger than `char`.

`wchar_t` is a larger type than `char` (well, it doesn't *have* to be larger, but it usually is). It represents the characters of the implementation-defined wide character set. On some implementations (most importantly, Windows, which uses surrogate pairs for characters outside the "basic multilingual plane"), it still isn't big enough to represent any Unicode character, which presumably is why the decoder you reference uses `int`.

You can't print wide characters using `printf`, because it deals in `char`. `wprintf` deals in `wchar_t`, so if the wide character set is unicode, and if `wchar_t` is `int` on your system (as it is on linux), then `wprintf` and friends will print the decoder output without further processing. Otherwise it won't.

In any case, you cannot portably print arbitrary unicode characters, because there's no guarantee that the terminal can display them, or even that the wide character set is in any way related to Unicode.

SQLite has probably used `unsigned char` so that:

- they know the signedness - it's implementation-defined whether `char` is signed or not.
- they can do right-shifts and assign out-of-range values, and get consistent and defined results across all C implementations. Implemenations have more freedom how `signed char` behaves than `unsigned char`.

Comment: @Appu: depends what the platforms are that you want to support, and whether you need to support all of Unicode or just the BMP, but probably not.

Answer (score 0):

Normal C strings are fine for storing utf8 data, but you can't easily search for a substring in your utf8 string.  This is because a character encoded as a sequence of bytes using the utf8 encoding could be anywhere from one to 4 bytes depending on the character.  i.e. a "character" is not equivalent to a "byte" for utf8 like it is for ASCII.

In order to do substring searches etc. you will need to decode it to some internal format that is used to represent Unicode characters and then do the substring search on that.  Since there are far more than Unicode 256 characters, a byte (or char) is not enough.  That's why the library you found uses ints.

As for your second question, it's probably just because it does not make sense to talk about negative characters, so they may as well be specified as "unsigned".

Comment: You can do substring searches in UTF-8 data just by looking for a matching sequence of bytes, provided that the UTF-8 data uses the canonical representation for each character (if not canonical, you can get false negatives). UTF-8 is cunningly designed to prevent false positives: you can tell by the top bits whether a given byte is the first byte of a character or not, so neither a subsequence of a character, nor the end of one character followed by the beginning of another, can possibly be confused for a different character.

Comment: @Wodin: Your answer is horribly wrong. @Steve: Each *character* has a unique representation in UTF-8. There are no non-canonical representations of characters, but there are multiple sequences of characters which are "canonically equivalent" to one another under Unicode - precomposed versus composing forms, and such. Whether you want to process or ignore these equivalences probably depends on what you're doing.

Comment: @R..: there aren't *supposed* to be non-canonical representations, but some utf-8 decoders behave as if there are, e.g. decoding `11000000 10000001` to U+01, so that you check your "UTF-8" input for `0x01`, think there aren't any, but later decode it and there are. So it depends how pedantic your decoder is or how trusted your input is. And yes, combining characters are also tricky so in practice if you can get away with defining equivalent sequences non-equal, you do. As you say, that's a general unicode issue, not utf-8 in particular.

Comment: Maybe this isn't an issue any more - if the last such non-verifying decoder has been put to pasture...

Comment: @Steve: Any decoder that decodes what you're calling non-canonical representations is *non-conforming* and *extremely dangerous*. If there's any such code in your project you should purge it immediately. In particular, the bytes 0xC0 and 0xC1 (along with 0xF5...0xFF) are completely invalid in UTF-8 and must always be rejected. There are certain other sequences which must be rejected too. UTF-8 decoding is best handled by a DFA, not traditional loops which are error-prone and tend to decode invalid inputs as aliases for valid strings.

Comment: @R..: sure, it was made non-conforming as of 2003, so I guess my concern might no longer be relevant.

Comment: I think you're looking at the IETF RFC, which was waaay behind. Unicode's definition of UTF-8 has always had a unique encoding for each character as far as I know.

Comment: Apparently I'm mistaken. Earlier versions of Unicode (pre-4.0) forbid a conforming implementation from generating these bogus "overlong sequences", but allowed an implementation to interpret them, despite that conflicting with another point in the text about all UTF forms having one-to-one mappings. The first version to declare interpretation of the incorrect forms non-conformant was Unicode 4.0, in 2003.

Comment: @R..: RFC-2279 (from 1998) states that _implementations [...] should protect against decoding invalid sequences_ and also has a _Security Considerations_ section dealing with this. Unfortunately it wasn't marked as MUST, but anyways...

Comment: @ninjalj: RFC 2279 is obsoleted by RFC 3629. It defined the valid legal UTF-8 sequences in terms of ABNF and defers to Unicode in case of conflict.

Comment: @R..: ah, so in 1998 it was a strong recommendation to protect against invalid sequences and in 2003 everyone turned that into a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a `substr` & `length` functions which supports UTF8 characters. This code is a modified version of what SQLite uses.

The following macro loops through the input text and skip all multi-byte sequence characters. `if` condition checks that this is a multi-byte sequence and the loop inside it increments `input` until it finds next head byte.

```
#define SKIP_MULTI_BYTE_SEQUENCE(input) {              \
    if( (*(input++)) >= 0xc0 ) {                       \ 
    while( (*input & 0xc0) == 0x80 ){ input++; }       \
  }                                                    \
}
```

`substr` and `length` are implemented using this macro.

```
typedef unsigned char utf8;
```

**substr**

```
void *substr(const utf8 *string, 
             int start, 
             int len, 
             utf8 **substring)
{
    int bytes, i;
    const utf8 *str2;
    utf8 *output;

    --start;
    while( *string && start ) {
        SKIP_MULTI_BYTE_SEQUENCE(string);
        --start;
    }

    for(str2 = string; *str2 && len; len--) {
        SKIP_MULTI_BYTE_SEQUENCE(str2);
    }

    bytes = (int) (str2 - string);
    output = *substring;
    for(i = 0; i < bytes; i++) {
        *output++ = *string++;
    }
    *output = '\0';
}
```

**length**

```
int length(const utf8 *string)
{
    int len;
    len = 0;
    while( *string ) {
        ++len;
        SKIP_MULTI_BYTE_SEQUENCE(string);
    }
    return len;
}
```